# Multiple CGAffineTranform statements dont give smooth results

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I'm applying a rotation and scaling on my UIView. **When I apply ONE of these transform, it works fine** but when I try to apply both the result is kind of not so smooth. It appears as it resets and the starts applying. Here's my code

```
var location:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
var rotatingLoaction:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
var deltaAngle: CGFloat!
func handleRotateAndResizeWithPanGestureRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void
{
    location = recognizer.location(in: self.superview)

    let sizeCenter = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width) / 2.0, y: (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height) / 2.0)
    
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        initialDistance = sizeCenter.getDistance(point: location)
        deltaAngle = atan2(location.y - sizeCenter.y, location.x - sizeCenter.x) - self.transform.getAngle()
    }
    else if recognizer.state == .changed
    {
        let ang = atan2(location.y - sizeCenter.y,
                          location.x - sizeCenter.x);
        let angleDiff = deltaAngle - ang;
        
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
        let distance = CGFloat(sizeCenter.getDistance(point: location))
        let scale =  distance / initialDistance
        t = t.rotated(by: -angleDiff)
        t = t.scaledBy(x:  CGFloat(scale), y: CGFloat(scale))
       
        self.transform  =  t
        
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
         print("\(center )    \(scale)")
    }
   
}
```

[image]

**Update Here's my getDistance Method which is written in CGPoint's extension**

```
func getDistance(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let fx = (point.x - self.x);
        let fy = (point.y - self.y);
        
        return sqrt((fx*fx + fy*fy))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the angle is working as expected, but not the scaling.
I can see that each time you begin a drag, you take account of the current angle of the view, but you don't take account of the current scaling. So the answer lies in scaling the view relative to its prior state each time you begin the drag.

I can't test this without a running example but I think that if you make this small change you may get the desired result:

```
if recognizer.state == .began {
    initialDistance = sizeCenter.getDistance(point: location) / sqrt(transform.a * transform.a + transform.c * transform.c)
```

Comment: I applied your code It works only when the view is parallel to X axis as I rotate the view towards parallel to y it jerks even more and decreases the size more as well.

Comment: and when the view is upside down and I try to scale it quickly rotates back

Comment: I added the getDistance Method in my question too. the value of a goes to negative when I rotate clockwise crossing y axis. So that also need to be considered

Comment: My bad, computing the scaling factor is a little bit more complex. I edited my answer. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-find-the-scale-from-a-cgaffinetransform